# Alignment of title in fig.suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to write title at the centre of the plot, however I am getting the following:

[image]

The following is the piece of my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69, 8.27))
fig.suptitle(r"$Ti_2$$Si_2$$Te_2$")
```

How to align the title at the centre?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation and image tags.

Comment: I want to make the alignment of title Ti_2 SI_2 Te_8 at the centre top of the plot. The pieces of code I posted are in two lines. Just need a command to align that title at centre. Thank you Nils.

Comment: The two lines you have posted, if used on their own, _does_ put the title at the centre of the figure. The problem must be elsewhere in your code. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with you David, it should be default at the centre, but is not showing . I tried with some other command but unable to solve this. I did not see any other problem.  Any suggestions, what might be the reason ? Thank you.

Comment: The suggestion is (as already stated) that you create a [mcve] of the issue. Once you have updated your question with this complete example, you will get a solution within some minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for nice suggestion. I will follow it in future posts.

Comment: This suggestion is meant for *this* post (of course any future post as well). If you ignore it, *this* post will be closed as off-topic soon enough (preventing you from getting any useful answer to *this* question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `horizontalalignment='center'` in `fig.suptitle` should fix it.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, and tried it, but it did not worked. It still remains at right top of the plot.  Thank you so much.

Comment: center is already the default value for `horizontalalignment`, so I'm not sure how this would help...